# Using or Access class variable from UIActionSheetDelegate Methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, uiactionsheet

in one of views in my app, which is subclass of UIView class, I have a button on toolbar(self.navigationController.toolBar). Once pressed, UIActionSheet pops up with 'delete' & 'cancel'.

myView.h

```
NSString *classVariable;
....
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *classVariable;
```

myView.m

```
@synthesize classVariable,...;
-(void) viewDidLoad {
     ...
     classVariable = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"blah"];
}
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
     if (buttonIndex == 0) {
     ...
     NSLog(classVariable);//BUG HERE!! just cannot printout and app gets sudden death.
     }
}
-(void)dealloc{
     ...
     [classVariable release];
}
```

I don't know why I cannot access to the variable from the UIActionSheetDelegate Method. I already declared the variable and give value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
     ...
     classVariable = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"blah"];
}
```

Comment: good point. no I did not. but the String variable is accessible from other normal methods. In other words, I can NSLog from other methods except UIActionSheet Delegate methods. that is my problem.

Comment: then i'm confused. in my own app i do plenty of stuff in such a method and it's just ok with that.

Comment: IB reference outlets were messed up. let me delete this thread later.

Comment: turned out it was not from the IB reference outlet mess ups.

Comment: Even though I couldn't figure out what I am missing, your advise is one big mistake I always make. so +1. many thanks